# Index performance on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm experiencing some troubles into making my query faster for production.

The query I want to execute currently takes 12 sec to show the resultset, and it crashes the production server which is ressource restricted.

The point is that I need to get all the `enregistrement` records when they are the last of the given `periode` (which is a date as YYYYMM).
After getting these records, I want to sum one of the fields given into `I.sum_field` as a `total` field.

When I comment the CASE part, the query takes approx 5sec (+/- 500ms).

Here is the query :

```
SELECT 
      I.libelle, 
      E1.periode, 
      E1.created_at, 
      CASE WHEN I.sum_field = 'fat' THEN SUM(E1.Fat)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'etp' THEN SUM(E1.Etp)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'nb_ident' THEN COUNT(*)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'cdi_actif' THEN SUM(E1.cdi_actif)
      END AS total
   FROM 
      indicateur_motif IM
         INNER JOIN indicateur I 
            ON IM.indicateur_id = I.id
         INNER JOIN `position` P 
            ON IM.motif_id = P.id
         INNER JOIN enregistrement E1 
            ON P.id = E1.position_id
            INNER JOIN 
               ( SELECT 
                       MAX(id) AS id, 
                       MAX(created_at) AS created_at
                    FROM 
                       enregistrement
                    WHERE 
                           (etat_mouvement_id IN (1,3,4))
                       AND (periode >= '201410' AND periode <= '201512')
                       AND created_at <= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
                    GROUP BY 
                       salarie_id, 
                       periode ) E2 
               ON E1.id = E2.id 
               AND E1.created_at = E2.created_at
   WHERE 
      I.formule_id = 1
   GROUP BY 
      I.id, 
      E1.periode
   ORDER BY 
      I.position, 
      E1.periode
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` result :

```
id  select_type  table           type    possible_keys                                   key                                             key_len  ref                   rows  Extra                                               
------  -----------  --------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------  -------  ------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------------
 1  PRIMARY      I               ALL     PRIMARY                                         (NULL)                                          (NULL)   (NULL)                  21  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort        
 1  PRIMARY      IM              ref     indicateur_motif_indicateur_id_motif_id_unique  indicateur_motif_indicateur_id_motif_id_unique  4        orhase.I.id              2  Using index                                         
 1  PRIMARY      P               eq_ref  PRIMARY                                         PRIMARY                                         4        orhase.IM.motif_id       1  Using index                                         
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>      ALL     (NULL)                                          (NULL)                                          (NULL)   (NULL)              165352  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  
 1  PRIMARY      e1              eq_ref  PRIMARY                                         PRIMARY                                         4        e2.id                    1  Using where                                         
 2  DERIVED      enregistrement  index   sp                                              sp                                              771      (NULL)              165352  Using where
```

Here is a sample of the resultset :

```
libelle                                     periode           created_at  total    
------------------------------------------  -------  -------------------  ---------
CDI actifs fin de période                   201410   2014-10-01 00:00:00  4689     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201411   2015-01-29 08:12:03  4674     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201412   2015-01-29 08:12:03  4660     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201501   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4444     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201502   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4222     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201503   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4195     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201504   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4176     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201505   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4155     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201506   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4136     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201507   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4121     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201508   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4080     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201509   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4061     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201510   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4036     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201511   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4001     
CDI actifs fin de période                   201512   2015-01-29 08:12:04  3976     
ETP fin de période CDI stock                201410   2014-10-01 00:00:00  4259.16  
ETP fin de période CDI stock                201411   2015-01-29 08:12:03  4241.91  
ETP fin de période CDI stock                201412   2015-01-29 08:12:03  4222.12  
ETP fin de période CDI stock                201501   2015-01-29 08:12:04  4028.07
```

I just have no idea where to put a new index to avoid this execution time... I've already put one on `enregistrement`, called `sp` :

`ALTER TABLE enregistrement ADD INDEX sp(salarie_id, periode);`

This one makes me get an execution time from 16sec to 12s.
Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this query really execute???

Comment: Yeah, but this is extremely slow, as i said...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but what is your case doing... You are summing totally different fields and counting another into a "Total".  I would suspect you might actually want these as their own columns.

However, that being said, what do you have for indexes... Your explain shows some, but I would try to include the following if they are NOT available...

```
table             index 
indicateur        ( formule_id, id, position )
indicateur_motif  ( indicateur_id, motif_id )
`position`        ( id )
enregistrement    ( position_id, id, created_at )  <-- for the JOIN portion
enregistrement    ( etat_mouvement_id, periode, created_at, salarie_id, id )  <-- for sub-select query
```

Also, from your joins, you are not really using anything from the 'Position' table.  Yes, you join from motif to position, position to enreg, but since

```
IM.motif_id = P.id  and  P.id = E1.position_id
```

then you could jump directly

```
IM.motif_id = E1.position_id
```

and remove the 'position' table from the query.  Here is a slightly revised query to what you started.  I removed the position reference, and also changed the "group by" of the inner query so that it might be better performance matching the available index for columns periode, and salarie_id.

```
SELECT 
      I.libelle, 
      E1.periode, 
      E1.created_at, 
      CASE WHEN I.sum_field = 'fat' THEN SUM(E1.Fat)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'etp' THEN SUM(E1.Etp)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'nb_ident' THEN COUNT(*)
           WHEN I.sum_field = 'cdi_actif' THEN SUM(E1.cdi_actif)
      END AS total
   FROM 
      indicateur I 
         JOIN indicateur_motif IM
            ON I.id = IM.indicateur_id
            INNER JOIN enregistrement E1 
               ON IM.motif_id = E1.position_id
               INNER JOIN 
                  ( SELECT 
                          MAX(id) AS id, 
                          MAX(created_at) AS created_at
                       FROM 
                          enregistrement
                       WHERE 
                              etat_mouvement_id IN (1,3,4)
                          AND periode >= '201410' 
                          AND periode <= '201512'
                          AND created_at <= '2015-02-03'
                       GROUP BY 
                          periode,
                          salarie_id ) E2 
                  ON E1.id = E2.id 
                  AND E1.created_at = E2.created_at
   WHERE 
      I.formule_id = 1
   GROUP BY 
      I.id, 
      E1.periode
   ORDER BY 
      I.position, 
      E1.periode
```

Comment: You were completely right on the `position` joins, I just patched this. Now, I tried your indexes and query suggestion, but I got same results or worse. (around 12~16sec to exec). You can check my answer, I got a new version of my query which takes around 6.7s to exec, with just one INDEX.

Comment: @user2236078, great on the position and new query to 7sec... but still too slow, right???  What is the overall basis of what you are trying to pull out (based on inner query to the outer context).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your tables look like, but this query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
FROM enregistrement

WHERE (etat_mouvement_id IN (1,3,4))
AND (periode >= '201410' AND periode <= '201512')
AND created_at <= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
GROUP BY salarie_id, periode
```

is very expensive. If you want to try to fix this solely through indexes, adding indexes to the `id` and `created_at` columns might be a good start. The other suggestion I might make is to run this query in a separate transaction, and insert the results into a temp table. That should at least free up some of the required resources by turning it into a simple join rather than a very complex search operation in the middle of your query. If that doesnt work, you could also try running all of the selects and joins without the sums, inserting those results into a temp table, and then selecting and summing the results from there.

That said, without seeing your tables, the number of rows in each and all of the data in each column, what kind of hardware youre running, or having any idea what your prod environment looks like  in regards to usage, its really hard to say exactly where the problem might be. I'm pretty sure there is no built-in function in MySQL yet, but profiling the query using something like Jet Profiler might be worthwhile if this is business critical. Seeing exactly where the resource pressure is coming from would be the first thing I would want to do if I were writing a query that is crashing production servers.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but : the subquery is not so expensive after adding an index to it (see my answer) and takes only 0.003s per execution. Other point my tables are simple : there is around 160k inserts in `enregistrement` table, and the other ones are around 10~200 inserts. Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

your slowness is coming from your sub-select on enregistrement.  they are both seem to be table scanning what looks all the records.  The IN is also not helping.

try creating indexes on the following table fields and let me know.

```
enregistrement.etat_mouvement_id
enregistrement.periode
enregistrement.created_at
```

Comment: Adding individual column indexes is of less value than a composite index (multiple fields as one index) based on criteria, group by and order by conditions.

Comment: My suggestion was to simply add indexing, you are correct composite indexing in this case will most definitely result in better querying speed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I mentionned in my answer, with only one composite index, I reduced execution time by 2. Now, I need to reduce the time needed for the GROUP BY and CASE commands. Creating useless INDEX entries is not good for performance purposes as I seen on many articles, so I just want to aim the right INDEX what are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. I reduced the execution time from 12s to 6.8s with this query :

```
SELECT I.libelle, e1.periode,
    CASE WHEN I.sum_field = 'fat'  THEN SUM(E1.Fat)
         WHEN I.sum_field = 'etp'  THEN SUM(E1.Etp)
         WHEN I.sum_field = 'nb_ident'  THEN COUNT(*)
         WHEN I.sum_field = 'cdi_actif' THEN SUM(E1.cdi_actif) END AS 'total'

        FROM indicateur_motif IM
        INNER JOIN indicateur I ON IM.indicateur_id = I.id
        INNER JOIN enregistrement e1 ON IM.motif_id = e1.position_id
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT MAX(created_at) AS createdat, salarie_id, periode
            FROM enregistrement 
            WHERE  (etat_mouvement_id IN (1,3,4))
            AND (periode >= '201410' AND periode <= '201512')
            AND created_at <= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            GROUP BY salarie_id, periode
        ) e2 ON (e1.created_at = e2.createdat AND e1.salarie_id = e2.salarie_id AND e1.periode = e2.periode)

    WHERE I.formule_id = 1 
    GROUP BY I.id, e1.periode
    ORDER BY I.position, e1.periode
```

Just for information, this subquery :

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS createdat, salarie_id, periode
FROM enregistrement 
WHERE  (etat_mouvement_id IN (1,3,4))
AND (periode >= '201410' AND periode <= '201512')
AND created_at <= DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
GROUP BY salarie_id, periode
```

Only takes 0.003s to execute, thanks to my `sp` index :

```
ALTER TABLE enregistrement ADD INDEX sp(salarie_id, periode);
```

**@DRapp** : You were right on my JOINS, I removed `position` from the joins and corrected the query. On total field, I do want to get the values on a single column, to not to do conditions on my code logic.

I tried **@DRapp** indexes and query proposition, they just slowed or changed nothing to my query.

```
id  select_type  table           type    possible_keys                                   key                                             key_len  ref                                  rows  Extra                                               
------  -----------  --------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------  -------  ---------------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------------
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>      ALL     (NULL)                                          (NULL)                                          (NULL)   (NULL)                             165352  Using temporary; Using filesort                     
 1  PRIMARY      e1              ref     sp                                              sp                                              771      e2.salarie_id,e2.periode                1  Using where                                         
 1  PRIMARY      I               ALL     PRIMARY                                         (NULL)                                          (NULL)   (NULL)                                 21  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  
 1  PRIMARY      IM              eq_ref  indicateur_motif_indicateur_id_motif_id_unique  indicateur_motif_indicateur_id_motif_id_unique  8        orhase.I.id,orhase.e1.position_id       1  Using index                                         
 2  DERIVED      enregistrement  index   sp                                              sp                                              771      (NULL)                             165352  Using where
```

With this EXPLAIN result, I want to resolve the first line, which describes `Using temporary; Using filesort`. The solution would be to index the GROUP BY columns, but I dont know if it's possible to create a composite index on these two fields, because they come from different tables. What would be a better or an alternative solution ?

Thanks all for your answers :)